# Problema con menu Desplegable + Boton en HTML

Tags: html, jquery

Tengo un menú que se despliega al presionar un botón y me muestra las opciones del menú, el problema es que aparece encima del cuerpo de mi pagina, y quisiera que por cada vez que se hace click en el botón desplace el cuerpo 1cm hacia abajo.

*También lograría el mismo efecto agregando un `padding-bottom` al menú de 1cm de espacio.*

Este es el menú:

```
<header class="bg-dark-red py-1" id="menu_top">
    <div class="container">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light" id="menu_nav">
            <h1>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
                    <img src="images/aki_logo.jpg" width="250" style="border-radius: 10px;">
                </a>
            </h1>


            <!--BOTON MENU-->
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation" id="boton_menu">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <!--_____________________-->

            <input type="hidden" class="btn_navbar">

            <!--ELEMENTOS DEL MENU-->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul class="navbar-nav ml-lg-4 mr-auto">
                    <li>
                        <input type="button" onclick="document.location.reload();" class="button_inicio" value="Inicio">
                    </li>

                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#Acerca_de" data-ancla="Acerca_de">Quienes Somos</a>
                    </li>

                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#Planes" data-ancla="Planes">Planes</a>
                    </li>

                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#Servicios" data-ancla="Servicios">Servicios Adicionales</a>
                    </li>

                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#Contacto" data-ancla="Contacto">Contacto</a>
                    </li>

                </ul>
                <!--<div class="header-right">
                    <a href="signin.html" class="signin mr-4">Sign in <i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt"></i></a>
                    <a href="register.html" class="contact">Get Started</a>
                    </div>-->
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>
```

Y este es solo una animación que le agrego al botón del menú.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    const btn = document.querySelector('.navbar-toggler')

    btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
        btn.classList.remove('animate')
        setTimeout(() => btn.classList.add('animate'), 100)
    })

</script>
```

Intenté agregar dentro del evento click esta linea.

```
document.getElementById('menu_top').style.paddingBottom = '1cm';
```

Agregué el **`id`** al header también, pero no funcionó.

Añado que también el botón del menú aparece solo si la resolución de pantalla es inferior a 1024x600 píxeles. Y me oculta los elementos de mi menú.

Y para el caso de ser superior la resolución, solo se muestran los elementos de mi menú, alineados. Y el botón se oculta.

Comment: Solo quieres que no te aparezca sobre el contenido de tu pagina? o aparte de esto agregarle un espacio?

Comment: Si asi es, despues de hacer click en el botón de mi menú, el menú se despliegue y adicionalmente agregue un espacio debajo para que no aparezca sobre el cuerpo de mi pagina. Ya que de manera original esta oculto el menú, y es transparente.

Comment: Respecto a lo que agregaste, es el comportamiento correcto de una navbar. Según la ejecución de mi ejemplo, es el comportamiento que se está logrando. Quieres algo distinto? no se entiendo que es lo que pretendes hacer.

Comment: @FranIslas. Es como tu ejemplo, pero lo aplique y no me funcionó, al momento de pinchar el botón me muestra el menú, luego solo intento que me desplace el contenido de mi sitio hacia abajo, o como _2da opción_ agregue un `padding-bottom` al menu despues de haberse desplegado. Es eso, espero que se haya entendido

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te dejo un ejemplo de como hacerlo para que el menú no te aparezca sobre el cuerpo de la pagina. No entendí bien si aparte de esto querías agregarle un espacio al desplegarlo, para esto agregue una linea de css. Basta con removerla si no es lo que necesitas. Saludos!

```js
document.getElementById('menu_top').style.paddingBottom = '1cm';

    const btn = document.querySelector('.navbar-toggler')

    btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
        btn.classList.remove('animate')
        setTimeout(() => btn.classList.add('animate'), 100)
        
    })
```

```css
/*Solo para distinguir el contenido*/
.contenido{height:100px;background-color:red}

/*Seleccionamos el menú solo cuando está desplegado y le agregamos padding*/

.navbar-collapse.collapse.show{padding-bottom: 2em;}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>




<header class="bg-dark-red py-1" id="menu_top">
    <div class="container">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light" id="menu_nav">
            <h1>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
                    <img src="images/aki_logo.jpg" width="250" style="border-radius: 10px;">
                </a>
            </h1>


            <!--BOTON MENU-->
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation" id="btn_menu">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <!--_____________________-->

            <input type="hidden" class="btn_navbar">
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul class="navbar-nav ml-lg-4 mr-auto">
                    <li>
                        <input type="button" onclick="document.location.reload();" class="button_inicio" value="Inicio">
                    </li>

                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#Acerca_de" data-ancla="Acerca_de">Quienes Somos</a>
                    </li>

                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#Planes" data-ancla="Planes">Planes</a>
                    </li>

                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#Servicios" data-ancla="Servicios">Servicios Adicionales</a>
                    </li>

                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#Contacto" data-ancla="Contacto">Contacto</a>
                    </li>

                </ul>
                
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>
<div class="contenido"><h3>Contenido de la pagina</h3></div>
```

Comment: Agregué esta linea: `.navbar-collapse.collapse.show{padding-bottom: 2em;}` pero no funciona, además actualice la pregunta añadiendo unos detalles acerca del botón.

Comment: Lo intente de esta manera: **`<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#boton_menu').click(function(){
     space.classList.remove('AgregaEspacio')
       setTimeout(() => space.classList.add('AgregaEspacio'),100)
    });
   </script>`** Y logré que me añadiera un espacio, pero no lo quita al volver a presionar sobre el boton del menu.

Answer (score 0):

prueba a agregar este css:

```
#navbarSupportedContent{
   display:block;
}
```

Comment: No solo es poner código, agrega una explicación del mismo